# Не могу зайти на сайт. выдает ошибку DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: хостинг, dns

Сегодня установил WP на хостинг, но я почему-то не могу зайти на сайт. Появляется такая ошибка **DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN** Очищал кэш DNS, отключал антивирус. На других браузерах и на телефоне тоже не работает.

Вот сам сайт
https://victoria-ariel.com/

Comment: Нет, не доступен. Обновление информации днс может занимать до 72 часов, т е. 3х дней. Ждите.